# Origen de la frase "se lo lleva el que lo trajo" y países de uso

Tags: etimología, diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, dialectos

Oyendo por enésima vez *Florentino y el diablo*, un joropo basado en un (interesante) poema de Alberto Torrealba, caía en cuenta de un verso en el que uno de los protagonistas le menciona al otro:

> (...)antes que Dios amanezca
>   se lo lleva quien lo trajo;(...)

Caí en cuenta que a alguien *se lo lleva quien lo trajo* no es habitual en todo el mundo hispano (Empecemos por definir la frase como: le va mal, pero realmente mal, en mayúsculas) aunque al menos, me consta su uso en Colombia y Venezuela. El Diccionario de americanismos lo reporta en El Salvador y República Dominicana, así creería que la frase tiene un uso en dialectos caribeños, centroamericanos y cercanos.

Al menos recuerdo, entre otros sinónimos en mi país, que te lleva el carajo, el diablo, el patas y por obra de Chespirito, también te puede llevar el chanfle (valga para incluir a México en sus sinónimos). Si bien parece que todas surgen del diablo como *"llevador"*,cuyas apariciones vienen desde antes del siglo XIX, los sinónimos solo vienen desde 1940 (según me muestra Google ngrams). Así pues, la frase se mostraría como un eufemismo de mediados del siglo anterior. ¿Es ese el origen de la frase y se usa solo en los 4 países del párrafo anterior?

Answer (score 0):

La frase "**se lo lleva el que lo trajo**" es un modismo o expresión popular que se utiliza para indicar que una persona es responsable de las consecuencias de sus acciones o decisiones. La frase hace referencia a que una persona debe hacerse cargo de aquello que ha traído consigo.

Esta expresión es común en varios países de habla hispana, especialmente en México, pero también se utiliza en otros países como Argentina, Chile, Colombia, Perú, entre otros. También puede encontrarse en algunos países de habla portuguesa, como Brasil, donde la expresión es "**quem trouxe o boi que o carregue**", que significa "**quien trajo el buey, que lo cargue**".